# Sum of array excluding the maximum and the minimum number

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, max, min

I have to add up excluding the minimum and maximum of any list of numbers.
This code work but it possible using a better solution only with 2 if and do not using a min/max function or another sum  function pre existent?

```
def total(array):
    sum = 0
    min = array[0]
    max = array[0]
    for x in array:
        if x>max:
            if max != min:
                sum += max
            max = x
    elif x == max:
        pass
    elif x < min:
        if min != max:
            sum += min
        min = x
    elif x == min:
        pass
    else:
         sum+=x
print(min)
print(max)
return sum
```

Comment: First, your code does not actually work, indentation is wrong. Second why would you not use sum, min and max, it allows for a short, readable solution?

Comment: because it's an assignment, homework...

Answer (score 0):

This solution utilizes more off-the-shelf functions as opposed to fewer. That said, it only uses the traditional scientific computing stack so it's something you might want to become familiar with at some point depending on your goals. Most importantly, it makes the solution much more readable.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xs = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,12])
xs[xs.between(np.min(xs),np.max(xs), inclusive=False)].sum()
```